# why are there (slightly) different statistics among different websites for the same fund?

Tags: mutual-funds, expense-ratio

I generally assume the statistics (especially expenses-related statistics) for any given fund should be the same across different websites as they collect the information from the same resource/origin.
But I came across the following example and am seeking some clarity and the best practice to find the accurate statistics. Thanks.

GMWAX (GMO Global Asset Allocation Fund)

On Bloomberg  https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/GMWAX:US

> front load: 0.15%; back load: 0.15%; expense ratio: --

On market watch https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/gmwax

> front load: 0.11%; deferred load: NA; expense ratio: 0%

On morningstar https://www.morningstar.com/funds/XNAS/GMWAX/quote.html

> expenses: 0.56%; load: none

On New York Times https://markets.on.nytimes.com/research/markets/mutualfunds/snapshot.asp?symbol=GMWAX

> front load: n.a.; total expense ratio: 0.57%

Comment: Not a definitive answer, I looked up that fund in [SEC Edgar](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html) and found [for GMWAX](https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?CIK=GMWAX&owner=exclude&action=getcompany&Find=Search) a [recent amendment](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/772129/000114420418036648/0001144204-18-036648-index.htm). Clicking on the first document and searching within for the full name will list current (as of Jun 30, 2018) fees. A spot check of similar SEC documents shows changes in fee percentages from an earlier period.

Comment: @Morrison, Thanks for the input. From your comments, are you suggesting that the best practice is to go to US SEC for the official documentation of the numbers, changes if any and other relevant information?

Comment: I don't know what you are doing with these fees/costs (in my mind 'statistics' can at least be duplicated via methodology, these are fees). I don't know if some of the other sources (NYT, Morningstar, etc.) include middle-man costs or are using some other source which is what your question is about. My understanding is that the fee schedule is in the fund prospectus and should match what the fund company reports to the SEC. Comparing your collected data for a public open-ended fund's prospectus may be appropriate rather than a close-end? institutional fund where custom agreements may apply.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that some websites are reporting the fund's gross expense ratio while others are reporting the net expense ratio.  Funds sometimes use expense waivers to temporarily reduce the expense ratio.  The below is a screenshot of a fund provider's website as of 2020-05-08.

**Edit:** This is not a recommendation for or against any fund.

[image: screen grab from mutual fund provider website]